# Проблемы с чтением из websocket golang

Tags: golang, websocket

Я пишу сервер с вебсокетами на golang. Накидал простой скрипт для теста:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/gobwas/ws"
)

func HandleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        header, err := ws.ReadHeader(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := make([]byte, header.Length)
        _, err = io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(buf)
        fmt.Println(string(buf))
    }
}

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        _, err = ws.Upgrade(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go HandleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

Делаю в консоле браузера:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
socket.send("Hello world")
```

И в терминале у меня выводятся какие-то рандомные байты. При каждом `socket.send("Hello world")` разные. Что это такое и почему они меняются при каждой отправке? Откуда он берёт эти байты? Количество байтов всегда соответствует количеству символов в строке, т.е. читает он то что надо. Делал как в документации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

данные приходят зашифрованные, нужно их дешифровать.

```
func HandleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        // привер простой
        // ws.ReadHeader(conn)
        // msg, _, err := wsutil.ReadClientData(conn)
        // if err != nil {
        //  panic(err)
        // }
        //
        // fmt.Println(msg)
        // fmt.Println(string(msg))

        // пример немного сложный
        header, err := ws.ReadHeader(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := make([]byte, header.Length)
        _, err = io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
         
        // вот это было добавленно
        if header.Masked {
            ws.Cipher(buf, header.Mask, 0)
        }

        fmt.Println(buf)
        fmt.Println(string(buf))
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю почему он зашифрованы) Я же не использую ssl/tls, с чего бы им шифроваться? Или это особенность работы tcp протокола о которой я не знаю?

Comment: 10 лет назад выкатили новую версию протокола,  где каждый обмен данными шифруется. [ссылка](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-07#section-4.3)